# Google Voice number doesn't work with Google Fabric?

Tags: google-fabric

I have been trying to create an account on digits with a Google Voice number. Whenever I enter my Google Voice phone number, the digits login screen simply shows an infinite loading icon. When checking the console, I see that a 403 message was generated for "digits (dot) com / sdk / login" and the following error message was returned:

"We cannot send a text message to this phone number because its operator is not supported".

The voice account was created about 12 hours ago.

I am not sure if Google Voice is supported, but now that Digits has been acquired by Google, I think its only logical that it should be supported.

It is important that I get this account to work, because I need it in order have a "developer account" for testers to use in the App Store review process.

I would like to know if there is anything that I can do about this, or if there is any type of help I can get from the team.

Comment: This isn't a programming question; it's a tech support question. Not a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: I am currently developing an application with Twitter (or now Google) Digits. My application is returning a technical error "We cannot send a text message to this phone number because its operator is not supported". Where else am I supposed to search for support? This is now the official developer portal for Digits.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If you have issues with a specific carrier or number, contacting support(at)fabric(dot)io is the best way to get help. We monitor SO for questions, but our support team is available via that email address.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate the response. I'll reach out soon to that email address with my question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> "We cannot send a text message to this phone number because its operator is not supported".

Seems pretty cut and dry there. A lot of services don't allow the use of a Google Voice number because it is a VOIP number. It is relatively easy to get a GV number, so some services block/don't whitelist their (and other VOIP's) numbers to prevent bots or mass accounts from abusing their services.

Whatever their reason is, it still doesn't work. As for actually getting it to work, I would contact the team and see if they can do anything, but it doesn't look like there is something *you* can do.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I completely agree with and understand what you are saying. I feel that Google Voice in particular should be supported due Digits' affiliation with Google. Twitter, for example, supports all Google Voice numbers, so I find it strange that Digits does not.